# Boost Python: Extended class objects inaccessible outside class definition

Tags: python, c++, python-3.x, boost-python

I'm using boost-python to extend a C++ callback class in python and receive data from server.

My C++ callback class has a virtual method called `handleMsg`, which I'm overriding in python. In the override, I'm appending the incoming 'msg' to a list.

**Here is my C++ Callback wrapper**

```
void export_Callback()
{
    class_< Callback>("Callback")
        .def(init<Callback>())
        .def("handleMsg", &Callback::handleMsg)
    ;
}
```

**Here is the python child class**

```
class SampleCallback(Callback):

    #numOfMsgs = 0
    #msgList = []
    def __init__(self):
        print('Initialising Callback...')        
        self.msgList = []
        self.numOfMsgs = 0
        Callback.__init__(self)

    def handleMsg(self, msg):        
        print('msg received')
        self.msgList.append(msg)
        print('Repr of list in class:')
        print(object.__repr__(self.msgList))
        self.numOfMsgs += 1
        self.printNumMsgs() #This gives updated value
        self.printList()      

    def getMsgList(self):
        return self.msgList

    def printList(self):
        print(self.msgList)

    def getNumOfMsgs(self):
        return self.numOfMsgs

    def printNumMsgs(self):
        print('Number of Messages in callback: '+str(len(self.msgList)))
```

**Here is how I'm starting my application**

```
    cb = SampleCallback();
    startServer()
    time.sleep(10)    
    startCppClient(cb) #cpp client sends messages to this object

    time.sleep(10)

    print('cb list size: '+str(len(cb.msgList)))
    print('Repr of list outside class:')
    print(object.__repr__(cb.msgList))
    print('cb num Of Msgs: '+str(cb.getNumOfMsgs()))
    print('Accessing print methods:')
    cb.printList() #This gives empty list
    cb.printNumMsgs()
```

**Here is the console log:**

```
Initialising Callback...
Starting Server 
Starting Client


msg received
Repr of list in class:
<list object at 0x7fd99e6b4dc8>
Number of Messages in callback: 1
[<component.msg object at 0x7fd99cf6fe08>]


msg received
Repr of list in class:
<list object at 0x7fd99e6b4dc8>
Number of Messages in callback: 2
[<component.msg object at 0x7fd99cf6fe08>, <component.msg object at 0x7fd99cf67868>]



cb list size: 0
Repr of list outside class:
<list object at 0x7fd99e6b4dc8>
cb num Of Msgs: 0
Accessing print methods:
[]
Number of Messages in callback: 0
```

As you can see, the object.**repr**() method is printing the same value inside the class definition, and the object instance, so I conclude that the same list is being updated.

However, the list seems populated when the `handleMsg` method is called from the base class, but the list member of the `cb` object is empty.

What am I doing wrong here ?

Any guidance is earnestly appreciated. Thanks